# Concatenar valores com condição (case)

Tags: sql, concatenação-de-string, case, cte

Boa noite! Sou novo na programação.

Tenho o código abaixo numa CTE que conta a quantidade de inscritos em cada área.

Na consulta principal eu vejo qual área tem maior quantidade de inscrito.

Eu gostaria de retornar o valor numérico conforme já está aparecendo, porém concatenar com o nome da  área de interesse maior. Porém não estou conseguindo pois um valor é inteiro e o outro string. Ou pelo menos colocar o nome da area com maior quantidade em outra coluna. Poderiam me ajudar? Obrigado

```
WITH CTE AS(

     SELECT TOP 1 INSCRITO.IDPS AS ID,
```

(SELECT

```
   COUNT (*) AS A FROM INSCRITO

     WHERE IDAREAINTERESSE = 51 ) AS A,
```

(SELECT
COUNT (*) AS A FROM INSCRITO

```
    WHERE IDAREAINTERESSE = 52 ) AS B,
```

(SELECT

```
   COUNT (*)  FROM INSCRITO

    WHERE IDAREAINTERESSE = 53) AS C

                                          

      FROM INSCRITO) SELECT ID,

                                             (CASE

                                                 WHEN A > B AND A > C THEN  A
                                                 WHEN B > A AND B > C THEN  B
                                                 WHEN C > A AND C > B THEN  C

                                               END) AS MAIOR,

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

                                             (CASE

                                              WHEN A < B AND A < C THEN  A
                                              WHEN B < A AND B < C THEN B

                                              WHEN C < A AND C < B THEN  C
                                               END) AS MENOR

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       


                   FROM CTE
```

Comment: *"pois um valor é inteiro e o outro string"*, então é só converter o valor inteiro para string

Comment: Se estiver utilizando o PostgreSQL utilize a função `to_char` para formatar seu valor numérico para string da forma desejada.

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados?

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite,

Segue uma sugestão para testes:

```
WITH 
  CTE_COUNT AS
  (
    SELECT
      IDPS AS ID,
      IDAREAINTERESSE,
      COUNT(*) AS QTDE
    FROM INSCRITO
    WHERE
      IDAREAINTERESSE IN (51, 52, 53)
    GROUP BY
      IDPS,
      IDAREAINTERESSE
  ),

  CTE_RN AS
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY QTDE) AS RN_ASC,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY QTDE DESC) AS RN_DESC
    FROM CTE_COUNT
  )

SELECT 
  A.ID,
  A.IDAREAINTERESSE AS MENOR_AREA,
  A.QTDE AS MENOR_QTDE,
  D.IDAREAINTERESSE AS MAIOR_AREA,
  D.QTDE AS MAIOR_QTDE
FROM CTE_RN AS A
INNER JOIN CTE_RN AS D
  ON 
    D.ID = A.ID AND
    D.RN_DESC = 1
WHERE
  A.RN_ASC = 1
```

A primeira CTE é utilizada para fazer a contagem por ID e área, na segunda CTE é utilizada a função Row_number para numerar as linhas de forma ascendente e descendente para poder identificar as linhas com menor e maior valor, e no final é feita uma auto junção para que os valores menor e maior sejam retornados em uma única linha para cada ID.

Observações:

- evite se possível consultar várias vezes a mesma tabela para ter um melhor desempenho
- acho que a concatenação dos valores aumentaria a dificuldade para identificar o menor e o maior valor

Espero que ajude